# Issue with deploying maven project with multiple modules to Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

So I have two modules, let's call them moduleA and moduleB. My goal is to deploy both of them to Tomcat. Here is what I have done:

**parent pom.xml**

```
<project>
  ....
  <artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
  </modules>
  ....
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
 ...
</project>
```

**moduleA pom.xml**

```
<project>
  ...
  <parent>
     ...
     <artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
  </parent>
  ...
</project>
```

**moduleB pom.xml**

```
<project>
  ...
  <parent>
     ...
     <artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
  </parent>
  ...
</project>
```

The directory structure looks like this

```
Users/swidjaja/dev/parentProject
  pom.xml
  moduleA
    pom.xml
  moduleB
    pom.xml
```

These are the steps that I do to deploy it to Tomcat

1. [On Terminal] mvn clean install
2. [On Terminal] mvn eclipse:eclipse
3. [Eclipse] import project
4. [Eclipse] Create new Tomcat 7.0 server and add the two modules to Resources [Eclipse] Run Tomcat server

Running the Tomcat server, I got the following exception

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of  class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'awsCredentials' defined in file [/Users/swidjaja/dev/parentProject/moduleA/target/moduleA-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And here is what the file applicationContext.xml looks like

```
<beans>
  <bean id="awsCredentials" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="accessKey" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="secretKey" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

My guess here is that somehow I didn't deploy it correctly. The BasicAWSCredentials class is part of aws-java-sdk which is defined as dependency in parent pom.xml and it looks like this module is not deployed correctly to Tomcat.

What did I do wrong in my steps? What will be the correct way to deploy such project? I've been struggling with this for 2 days now.

Any help is highly appreciated. Many Thanks!